# istream with popen functionality

Tags: c++, fstream, popen, ifstream, istream

I have a function that accepts `istream` class.

I need to be able to make it work with gzip data.

Is there in C++ standard `istream`-like class with `popen()`-like functionality?

Alternatively, is there a way to convert `FILE *` to `istream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both approaches can be implemented by implementing a suitable stream buffer but neither approach is part of the C++ standard. I *think* there are implementations in [Boost](http://boost.org/).

Specifically for the use with `gzip`ped data I wouldn't use something spawning a process, though. Instead, I would create a stream buffer using the `gzip` library (which may also exist in Boost).